# database update notification in firebase for specific users

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to create an android application and would like to use firebase database. As I read firebase allows instant messaging and also notify  clients when database is updated. I need to create a database and when any database changes happen, related users needs to be notified only. Is that possible with firebase or should I use backend server for this purpose?

Answer (score 8):

You can do it using the Firebase only.
What you needs are

1. Firebase Database (Realtime database/Firestore)
2. Firebase Cloud Functions
3. Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)

You should write two side codes:

1. Client side (Android)
2. Server side (Cloud Functions)

In Client side (Android)

1. You should register token. (To send a notification using the FCM, Token is needed.) You can do this easily (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client)
2. I recommend that you can store the token into the database/firestore too.
   for example:

   class User {
       long id;
       String email;
       String token;
   }
3. You may write the code to modify the database/firestore.
4. Implement receiving code (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive)

In Server side (Cloud Functions)

1. Add some trigger to the database/firestore.
2. Get the token from the database/firestore
3. just send FCM message (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages)

You can get the sample code for Server side (Cloud Functions)
https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can achieve this using [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/) which:

> lets you automatically run backend code in response to events triggered by Firebase features and HTTPS requests. Your code is stored in Google's cloud and runs in a managed environment.

And with [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/) which:

> Is a cross-platform messaging solution that lets you reliably deliver messages at no cost. Using FCM, you can notify a client app that new email or other data is available to sync. You can send notification messages to drive user re-engagement and retention.

So you can write a function in `Firebase Cloud Functions` which will trigger a notification every time something is changing in your database. Both documetations are very well explained.